# Pipelines, Jobs and Processes in Zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, job-control, shell-builtin

I went through the [Jobs & Signals](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html#Jobs-_0026-Signals) documentation in Zsh, but some things aren't still clear to me. It says:

> If the `MONITOR` option is set, an interactive shell associates a job with each **pipeline**.

What exactly is a `pipeline` and what is the relationship between a `pipeline`, a `job` and a `process`? Is `MONITOR` enabled by default?

What type of operations can one do on `jobs` with Zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you type something like `ls -l|grep foo` your shell will start two *processes* (`ls` and `grep`). It will (because of the pipe `|`) also connect them to one *pipeline*. An interactive shell will also provide *job control*. This means you can do things like pausing a job or putting it in background.

Typing `sleep 10&` will run a process, the shell will also assign it a job and put that job in background. You can type `jobs` to see that job running. Also have a look at `fg` and `bg` as a way to put a job to foreground or background.

The [Monitor option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-MONITOR) is exactly the one enabling job control. The documentation says:

```
MONITOR (-m, ksh: -m)
    Allow job control. Set by default in interactive shells.
```